# saving workflow osx?

Tags: macos, automation, workflow, workspace, launcher

Can i automate opening several apps, and place windows on exact locations, so i can have a workflow ready with the click of a button?

example:

When working on developing different projects i often use a multitude of different applications, handling some project specific files, with windows set at exact locations over several screens. It can become quite tiresome to, open, close and rearange windows and apps when working on different projects.

In one web dev project i have textmate and firefox open on one screen and firebug console on a seperate screen, coupled with php.errorlog.

It would be amazing if could place a file on the desktop that would open all relevant applications, files and place windows properly troughout the screens.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can record your actions with the AppleScript Editor, and place the resulting file on your desktop. it's like macros in word ;) (but insanely powerful!)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't get recording actions to work but made a quick script to open a few applications and specific webpages. Couldn't rearrange the windows in 3. party apps yet though; do shell script "open -a MAMP"
do shell script "open -a Firefox http://localhost:8888/1/js/index.htm"
do shell script "open -a Firefox http://www.someothersite.com"

do shell script "open Applications/MAMP/htdocs/1/js/js.tmproj"

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use AutoIt from (www.autoitscript.com) It is easy to use. Amazing cool software, and it is free. I just made this script to test it, and it worked well. Evrything is simple and well explained in its helpfiles.

```
Run("notepad.exe")
Run("calc.exe")

WinWaitActive("[CLASS:Notepad]") ; you can define by class name
WinWaitActive("Calculator") ;you can define by title

If WinExists("[CLASS:Notepad]") Then ;you can check if window exist
    WinMove("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", 0, 0, 500, 500) ;move and resize
    WinMove("Calculator", "", 50, 300) ;only move
EndIf

WinActivate("[CLASS:Notepad]", "") ;activate a window

Sleep(3000) ;wait 3 seconds
WinClose("[CLASS:CalcFrame]", "") ; close a window
```

Comment: Looks great but right now i working mostly in osx. Will definitely look into it on my windows partition though!